# Question about an algebra of sets

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ and let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all subsets $A$ that fulfills the following form:
$$A=(A_1-A_2)\cup A_3=\Bigl(([a_1,b_1]\cup...\cup [a_k,b_k])-\{c_1,...,c_m\}\Bigl)\cup \{d_1,...d_n\}$$

where $A_1=[a_1,b_1]\cup...\cup [a_k,b_k]$, $A_2=\{c_1,...,c_m\} \subseteq A_1$, $A_3=\{d_1,...d_n\}$; $A_1 \cap A_3 = \emptyset$ and $[a_i,b_i]\cap [a_j,b_j]=\emptyset$. When $k=0$, $m=0$, or $n=0$, then $A_1=\emptyset$, $A_2=\emptyset$, or $A_3=\emptyset$ respectively.

It is easy to verify that $\mathcal F$ is an algebra. Let $L(A) = (b_1 - a_1) +...+ (b_k - a_k)$ and $N(A) = n-m$ if $A\ne \emptyset$; if $A=\emptyset$, then $L(A)=N(A)=0$.

Consider $A=(A_1-A_2)\cup A_3$ and $C=(C_1-C_2)\cup C_3$. Given $A\cap C=\emptyset$ and $L(A)=L(C)$, I would like to show that $N(A\cup C)=N(A) +N(C)+|A_1\cap C_1|$. I've been trying to prove this, but to no avail. Any help (or counterexample) are appreciated!

Comment: An alternate description of $\mathcal F$ is just the set of all finite unions of disjoint bounded intervals (presumably in $\Omega$, since you introduced it, but afterwards you made no more mention of it), where singleton points are considered closed intervals of $0$ length. $L(A)$ is still the sum of the lengths of the intervals making up $A$. $N(A)$ is the number of singletons in $A$ less the number of distinct open endpoints of intervals in $A$.

Comment: Yes, the disjoint bounded intervals are subsets of $\Omega$. Your alternative descriptions of the sets are correct.